# what are differences between kmalloc() kcalloc() vmalloc() and kzalloc()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, malloc, driver

```
Hi all,
```

I'm currently debugging a device driver and I'm getting a kernel panic. After checking the backtrace or the error log, it appears to be that the problem is with kmalloc. I was thinking maybe I could change kmalloc with other allocation functions. What are their differences?

here's the error log:

```
Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 0000000d
pgd = c7bdc000
[0000000d] *pgd=4785f031, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] PREEMPT
Modules linked in: bcm5892_secdom_fw(P) bcm5892_lcd snd_bcm5892 msr bcm5892_sci     bcm589x_ohci_p12 bcm5892_skeypad hx_decoder(P) pinnacle hx_memalloc(P) bcm_udc_dwc         scsi_mod g_serial sd_mod usb_storage
CPU: 0    Tainted: P           (2.6.27.39-WR3.0.2ax_standard #1)
PC is at __kmalloc+0x70/0xdc
LR is at __kmalloc+0x48/0xdc
pc : [<c0098cc8>]    lr : [<c0098ca0>]    psr: 20000093
sp : c7a9fd50  ip : c03a4378  fp : c7a9fd7c
r10: bf0708b4  r9 : c7a9e000  r8 : 00000040
r7 : bf06d03c  r6 : 00000020  r5 : a0000093  r4 : 0000000d
r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000094  r1 : 00000020  r0 : c03a4378
Flags: nzCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 00c5387d  Table: 47bdc008  DAC: 00000015
Process sh (pid: 1088, stack limit = 0xc7a9e260)
Stack: (0xc7a9fd50 to 0xc7aa0000)
fd40:                                     c7a6a1d0 00000020 c7a9fd7c c7ba8fc0
fd60: 00000040 c7a6a1d0 00000020 c71598c0 c7a9fd9c c7a9fd80 bf06d03c c0098c64
fd80: c71598c0 00000003 c7a6a1d0 bf06c83c c7a9fdbc c7a9fda0 bf06d098 bf06d008
fda0: c7159880 00000000 c7a6a2d8 c7159898 c7a9fde4 c7a9fdc0 bf06d130 bf06d078
fdc0: c79ca000 c7159880 00000000 00000000 c7afbc00 c7a9e000 c7a9fe0c c7a9fde8
fde0: bf06d4b4 bf06d0f0 00000000 c79fd280 00000000 0f700000 c7a9e000 00000241
fe00: c7a9fe3c c7a9fe10 c01c37b4 bf06d300 00000000 c7afbc00 00000000 00000000
fe20: c79cba84 c7463c78 c79fd280 c7473b00 c7a9fe6c c7a9fe40 c00a184c c01c35e4
fe40: 00000000 c7bb0005 c7a9fe64 c79fd280 c7463c78 00000000 c00a1640 c785e380
fe60: c7a9fe94 c7a9fe70 c009c438 c00a164c c79fd280 c7a9fed8 c7a9fed8 00000003
fe80: 00000242 00000000 c7a9feb4 c7a9fe98 c009c614 c009c2a4 00000000 c7a9fed8
fea0: c7a9fed8 00000000 c7a9ff64 c7a9feb8 c00aa6bc c009c5e8 00000242 000001b6
fec0: 000001b6 00000241 00000022 00000000 00000000 c7a9fee0 c785e380 c7473b00
fee0: d8666b0d 00000006 c7bb0005 00000300 00000000 00000000 00000001 40002000
ff00: c7a9ff70 c79b10a0 c79b10a0 00005402 00000003 c78d69c0 ffffff9c 00000242
ff20: 000001b6 c79fd280 c7a9ff64 c7a9ff38 c785e380 c7473b00 00000000 00000241
ff40: 000001b6 ffffff9c 00000003 c7bb0000 c7a9e000 00000000 c7a9ff94 c7a9ff68
ff60: c009c128 c00aa380 4d18b5f0 08000000 00000000 00071214 0007128c 00071214
ff80: 00000005 c0027ee4 c7a9ffa4 c7a9ff98 c009c274 c009c0d8 00000000 c7a9ffa8
ffa0: c0027d40 c009c25c 00071214 0007128c 0007128c 00000241 000001b6 00000000
ffc0: 00071214 0007128c 00071214 00000005 00073580 00000003 000713e0 400010d0
ffe0: 00000001 bef0c7b8 000269cc 4d214fec 60000010 0007128c 00000000 00000000


Backtrace:

[<c0098c58>] (__kmalloc+0x0/0xdc) from [<bf010a00>] (GadgetEpRequestAlloc+0x28/0x70 [bcm_udc_dwc])

 r8:bf017c80 r7:c79de2d8 r6:c79de2d8 r5:00000000 r4:00000040

[<bf0109d8>] (GadgetEpRequestAlloc+0x0/0x70 [bcm_udc_dwc]) from [<bf0181d4>] (gs_alloc_req+0x44/0xf0 [g_serial])

 r5:00000000 r4:00000040

[<bf018190>] (gs_alloc_req+0x0/0xf0 [g_serial]) from [<bf0182b4>]     (gs_alloc_requests+0x34/0xb4 [g_serial])

 r7:c79de2d8 r6:c79aa198 r5:00000000 r4:c79aa180

[<bf018280>] (gs_alloc_requests+0x0/0xb4 [g_serial]) from [<bf018368>] (gs_start_io+0x34/0xb8 [g_serial])

 r9:c7b84000 r8:c7b48c00 r7:c79aa198 r6:c79de2d8 r5:c79aa180
r4:c79aa180

[<bf018334>] (gs_start_io+0x0/0xb8 [g_serial]) from [<bf018730>] (gs_open+0x1d0/0x23c [g_serial])

 r9:c7b84000 r8:c7b48c00 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:c79aa180
r4:c7924300

[<bf018560>] (gs_open+0x0/0x23c [g_serial]) from [<c01c3754>] (tty_open+0x1dc/0x314)

[<c01c3578>] (tty_open+0x0/0x314) from [<c00a184c>] (chrdev_open+0x20c/0x22c)

[<c00a1640>] (chrdev_open+0x0/0x22c) from [<c009c438>] (__dentry_open+0x1a0/0x2b8)

 r8:c79aa300 r7:c00a1640 r6:00000000 r5:c74685a8 r4:c7a9f5a0

[<c009c298>] (__dentry_open+0x0/0x2b8) from [<c009c614>] (nameidata_to_filp+0x38/0x50)

[<c009c5dc>] (nameidata_to_filp+0x0/0x50) from [<c00aa6bc>] (do_filp_open+0x348/0x6f4)

 r4:00000000

[<c00aa374>] (do_filp_open+0x0/0x6f4) from [<c009c128>] (do_sys_open+0x5c/0x170)

[<c009c0cc>] (do_sys_open+0x0/0x170) from [<c009c274>] (sys_open+0x24/0x28)

 r8:c0027ee4 r7:00000005 r6:0007121c r5:0007129c r4:0007121c

[<c009c250>] (sys_open+0x0/0x28) from [<c0027d40>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x2c)
Code: e59c4080 e59c8090 e3540000 159c308c (17943103)

---[ end trace b9a765ee07f8c06b ]---
```

Comment: What is GadgetEpRequestAlloc()?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is very unlikely that kmalloc is broken, since it is used everywhere in the kernel. However, kmalloc can fail. Assuming that kmalloc is not broken then the code calling is a good candidate :

- How does the code around the kmalloc looks like ? Maybe you could show us that part.
- What is the part before the backtrace ? It can contain valuable information to.

To answer more directly to the question asked :

- kzalloc zeroes the memory before returning a pointer
- kcmalloc allocates memory for an array, it is not a replacement for kmalloc :

  void *kcalloc(size_t n, size_t size, gfp_t flags)
- vmalloc is the same as kmalloc, except that it allocates memory that is only virtually contiguous. The underlying physical memory can be discontiguous.

So kmalloc can eventually be replaced by a call to kzalloc, but it is unlikely to solve your problem .

Comment: the code around kmalloc is in the gs_alloc_req() of the file u_serial.c -> http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/gadget/u_serial.c

Comment: vmalloc is not the same as kmalloc. It allocates memory that is _not_ physically contiguous, only virtually contiguous.

Comment: @mpe I rephrased this part, is it ok ?

Answer (score 5):

I think the choice between the kmalloc, vmalloc and other allocation techniques lies in the implementation. The failure of each of them is also contingent. 
If you need multiple of pages of memory rather go with the pages allocation techniques. They are simple and fast as well.
However, if you need certain amount of data (expressed in terms of bytes) then the choice remains between kmalloc( and its variants) and vmalloc.
kmalloc is faster and provides the contiguous memory allocation( especially useful in the case of DMA). The algorithm implementing it is very fast. However, if your memory is highly fragmented then the problem may arise when you request for a large memory. If it can't find enough contiguous space, if fails despite the memory having enough space to accommodate. 
vmalloc on the other hand doesn't need the contiguous memory allocation. However, it is quite slow. It works by suitably setting up the page table entries. Furthermore, kernel usually doesn't allocate lots of space for the vmalloc.

So, in your case I think it is contingent on what type of applications you are using. However, using vmalloc instead of kmalloc isn't the solution most of the time( except for the large memory allocations in highly fragmented memory). In such cases you can directly opt for pages allocation.

Answer (score 2):

kmalloc could be culprit only when your memory is fragmented and fails allocating memory if it does not find contiguous memory. So depending on how big of chunk of memory you are trying to allocate.

In such cases, using vmalloc yields good results. In best practices,

1. if you want use kmalloc better use kzmalloc.
2. If your allocation is big better use vmalloc.

Now check what is best for you based on the error condition.